# Create a post_save signal that creates a profile object for me

Tags: python, django

Good afternoon, I have the following signal inside my User model, but at the moment of creating the user it is not creating the profile object, which I am doing wrong.

```
  def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.create_profile.save()

post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=User)
post_save.connect(save_profile, sender=User)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have an app called **profiles**
In `profiles/signals.py`

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

from profiles.models import Profile

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

In `profiles/app.py`

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class ProfilesConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'cmdbox.profiles'
    verbose_name = _('profiles')

    def ready(self):
        import cmdbox.profiles.signals  # noqa
```

Finally in `profiles/__init__.py`

```
default_app_config = 'profiles.apps.ProfilesConfig'
```

Answer (score 1):

create a signal.py file then add this peace of code there:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import Profile


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

then in your users apps.py add this code there:

```
class UsersConfig(AppConfig):
name = 'users'

    def ready(self):
        import users.signals
```

then you are done!